# Rails - Given a File Form Posted, How to Store in the DB and then Read later?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

Given a Rails Form Post with X number of files.

- How do you store the file in the Database?

Then, later, how do you then read the file?

Thanks.

A little more background. The file form post is from SendGrid's parse api. Then later I want to be able to read the file with delayed_job and then use paperclip to store the file and process it on S3.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure I just answered your other question the same way: https://github.com/jstorimer/delayed_paperclip does what you seem to want it to do.

Comment: Thanks but that's interesting but not a solution here for my app. I'm dealing with receiving a post from the SendGrid Parse API. And I can't use paperclip at this point as I don't know where/what it belongs to.

Comment: Are you able to provide a little more detail? There's a multitude of ways to do what you're trying to do, any of which could be the best option.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the limited information I know about your system, I'm assuming you've got some model that tracks the emails. That's a good start.

First I would like to clarify that in no situation should you be storing files *in the database*. Files go in the filesystem, where they can be read and written much faster.

Now with that in mind, I would have a model that associates with your email model, possibly called `Part`. This model's purpose will be to use Paperclip to store the files. I would call the attachment `part` also, and so to create a new one you would do this:

```
email.parts.build(:part => some_file)
```

In that case, Paperclip will take care of moving the file to where it needs to be. To read the file later, Paperclip has methods for that. Check out Paperclip's documentation, it's pretty good for this sort of thing.